# Symfony2 Doctrine Custom Query Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am creating a custom query in Symfony2 using doctrine. Anywho, the issue that I am having is that this script will not return any results unless there are records in all of the Joined in Tables. How can I ensure that I can get records back even if all the joined in tables dont have records.

Here is my code:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $dql = "    SELECT p, poli, polil, pops, pa
                FROM WIC\PurchaseOrderBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder p

                JOIN p.purchaseOrderLineItem poli
                  WITH poli.purchaseOrder=p.id

                JOIN poli.purchaseOrderLineItemLocation polil
                  WITH polil.purchaseOrderLineItem=poli.id

                JOIN polil.purchaseOrderProductsStatus pops
                  WITH pops.purchaseOrderLineItemLocation=polil.id

                JOIN pops.putAway pa
                  WITH pa.purchaseOrderProductsStatus=pops.id

                WHERE p.account=:account_id
                AND p.id=:id";
    $query = $em->createQuery($dql);
    $query->setParameters(array(
        'account_id' => $account->getId(),
        'id' => 10488,
    ));
    $purchaseorders = $query->getArrayResult();
```

Counting the Array:

```
 When I do a echo count(purchaseorders) it returns: 0
```

Printing the Array:

```
 When I do a print_r($purchaseorders) it returns: Array ( )
```

I would think that I should at least get back the purchase order info in the array even though there are no line items, line item locations, status's, or put away records.

Here is my test twig template, the error is not in here, just thought I'd add it anyways...

```
{% for purchaseorder in purchaseorders %}
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        Purchase Order: {{ purchaseorder.id }}
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                {% for purchaseorderitems in purchaseorder.purchaseOrderLineItem %}
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ purchaseorderitems.id }}<br>
                    {% for purchaseorderitemLocations in purchaseorderitems.purchaseOrderLineItemLocation %}
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ purchaseorderitemLocations.id }}<br>
                        {% for purchaseOrderProductsStatus in purchaseorderitemLocations.purchaseOrderProductsStatus %}
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ purchaseOrderProductsStatus.id }}<br>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As it is right now, I have added new Purchase Order, so that record does exist in the PurchaseOrder table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: loops in loops in loops in loops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should use a LEFT JOIN instead. Just figured it out, thought I would just leave the answer up there for anyone else if they needed it. Cheers!